# PHP MySQL Joining of few joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

There are 2 queries:

```
select * from gallery_images JOIN photo_galleries ON photo_galleries.albumID=gallery_images.albumID


select * from multimedia_video JOIN video_content ON multimedia_video.id=video_content.id_href
```

Also i have "albumDateCreated" field on "photo_galleries" table and "DateCreated" field on "multimedia_video". I want to sort my queries by these fields

What is the best technique to JOIN my 2 "joins"?

Answer (score 1):

Just the way you created the others:

```
SELECT * FROM gallery_images
    JOIN photo_galleries ON photo_galleries.albumID=gallery_images.albumID
    JOIN multimedia_video ON photo_galleries.albumDateCreated=multimedia_video.DateCreated
    JOIN video_content ON multimedia_video.id=video_content.id_href
```

Comment: Heh. Actually "DateCreated" and "albumDateCreated" are not common. I need to display all my photo and video albums on one cycle and order them by date where they was created.